# twisted module not found error from Python Flasky

Tags: python

I am having trouble in running a flask file that is manager.py on Windows 10. Although I installed requirements, it still aborts an import error.What's funny is the errors are different in PyCharm and cmd. And I activated the same virtual environment.I will appreciate it if someone can help me!

In PyCharm:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Online-serial-debugging/manage.py", line 6, in <module>
    from app import create_app
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Online-serial-debugging\app\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask.ext.twisted import twisted
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\online\Online-serial-debugging\enve\lib\site-packages\flask\exthook.py", line 87, in load_module
    raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named flask.ext.twisted.twisted

Process finished with exit code 1
```

In CMD:

```
(enve) C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\online\Online-serial-debugging>python manage.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 5, in <module>
    from flask.ext.script import Manager
ImportError: No module named flask.ext.script
```

Here are my requirments.txt:

```
construct==2.5.2
dominate==2.1.16
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-Bootstrap==3.3.5.3
Flask-Moment==0.5.0
Flask-Twisted==0.1.1
Flask-Script==2.0.5
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.7.3
MarkupSafe==0.23
observable==0.1.0
pyserial==2.7
six==1.10.0
Twisted==15.4.0
txsockjs==1.2.2
pypiwin32
Werkzeug==0.10.4
zope.interface==4.1.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. The problem is solved.orz. My command line is :

```
python manage.py
```

Actually, I used the Python interpreter in system path by mistake.And I run this command :

```
./enve/Scripts/python.exe manage.py
```

There are no import errors again, thank you who answered me still.

Answer (score 0):

Please fix your `import` statement as follows, and could you try?

`from flask_script import Manager`

**EDIT**

Sorry, even using `flask.ext.{}`, it seems still works.

If you run the following command, what come back?

`pip install Flask-Script==2.0.5`

Comment: I'm not sure if this will really fix the issue. While `flask.ext.{}` is depreciated, it still works for backwards compatibility

Comment: Sorry, as you say, even using `flask.ext.{}`, it seems still works.

Answer (score 0):

It means that 'Flask-Script' was not installed, check your 'pip freeze'.
Was there any error when installing the requirements? If so, try to identify the issue.

Try installing it:

```
$ pip install Flask-Script
```

Comment: There is no error when installing the requirements, and there was an output line when I ran the following command: pip install Flask-Script.                              
         Requirement already satisfied: Flask-Script in c:\users\administrator\desktop\online\online-serial-debugging\enve\lib\site-packages